# How to get everything after two specific characters in bash

Tags: bash

I want to put the numbers into different variables

So I have three lines for example with $1 being -a in the first line

```
number -a 3 1245 1234
```

second line, $1= -b

```
number -b 2 2345 64353
```

third line, $1= -a

```
number -a 5 -b 3 54525 545252
```

Is it possible to put the numbers in one variable if a and b are separated like line one and two and in two variables if they are combined
So for line one

```
number=3
```

line 2

```
number=2
```

line 3

```
number1=5
number2=3
```

and then to use in a echo statement

Comment: Put the contents of the line in an array. Loop over the array elements, and if the current element is `-a`, put the next element in `number1`. If the current element is `-b`, put the next element in `number2`.

Comment: *newprogrammer pro* ? where is *newprogrammer non-pro*? :-), When you say _lines_ what does that mean? A line in a text file or an argument to a command/program named `number`?

Answer (score 0):

Just do normal shell parsing for command line parameters.  Not practical to create conditions for parsing for 3rd pattern "number=".  Best to keep it to one for each of the options involved, that way you keep the distinct relationship with the original option flags.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "number -a 3 1245 1234
number -b 2 2345 64353
number -a 5 -b 3 54525 545252" |
while read line
do
    set -- ${line}
    shift           # eliminate command from line
    while [ $# -gt 1 ]
    do
        case $1 in
            -a ) echo "number1=$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
            -b ) echo "number2=$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
            * ) break ;;
        esac
    done
    echo ""
done
```